# run lightbox in jQuery by click on a button

Tags: jquery, lightbox

for running the lightbox in jquery you must click on one image('a' link) of the gallery then immediately lightbox runs....

```
$('#gallery a').lightBox();
```

but i am going to use the lightbox as a zoom, that means i have a button 'ZOOM', by clicking this buttom i am going to open my gallery...

i don't know how i can do this...

Comment: What is your lightbox plugin site? Did you check the API?

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about this plugin http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 6):

you could use:

```
     $('#gallery a').lightBox();
     $('#zoomButton').click(function(){
         $('#gallery a:first').click();
    })
```

Or possibly

```
$('#gallery a:first').trigger();
```

Untested but should work

Comment: thanks this work .... but it has a crazy trick.... i have to have 2 gallery with the same images.... one for zoom... another for rollover....

   $('#gallery a').lightBox();
     $('#zoomButton').click(function(){
         $('#gallery a:first').click();
    })